# develop webcamera with battery and memory to SELF RECORDING (Disc Processing System)

Tags: microcontroller, video, camera

In my studies projects I want to make an camera with

> 1. SD memory card or USB mass storage (which is simple)
> 2. micro-controller to translate commands (start recording, dump JPEG to SD card to make video, or many JPEG files )
> 3. battery supply compatible with camera module and the micro-controller and the SD card supply

please is there any one who can help me with exact details about the schematics and the components list or redirect me to an existing succeeded projects like that

because I am new in electronics and this is in my project studies what I have selected.

Comment: What's the "disc"? A hard disk?

Comment: You may do better to reconsider your choice of project, as you are going to have a hard time coming close to what is available at low cost off the shelf.  Try to pick something where you can innovate, cover new territory, or at least do more than combine a highly integrated camera module with a file system library.  Even if you wanted to add features not found on the $12 sd recording cameras, you'd likely be better off with a used/prepaid android phone as a platform for software development than with custom hardware.

Answer (score 2):

[This camera module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8667) is only 6 mm \$\times\$ 6 mm, so it should fit in any device.

[image]

It has an 8-bit parallel interface for data, plus an I2C interface for control. Just 10 dollar.

For the storage you may want an **SD-card**. The requirements for the microcontroller aren't that high: all it has to do is capture the data and pump it to the SD-card. This entry-level [Cortex-M0](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC111X.pdf) controller can run at 50 MHz and can easily handle the data throughput.

Comment: please help me more to connect the micro controller with the module to record video to the SD card ! it's very urgent

Comment: @Student - Sorry, but that's not the way this site works. Everybody here (including me) does this in his own time. We're prepared to help you, but you can't push us. I will have to study the camera's datasheet, and that's 27 pages long for me as well as for you. It will take some time, I'll look at it, but not now: lunch time. Until now you haven't shown any effort yourself. Try to read some documents, here on EE.SE or elsewhere on the 'Net. Something has to come from you. If you expect a complete design, or if it's urgent, you'll have to hire a consultant.

Comment: yes i know and thanks very much for your help, but i want to link me to successed projects using module camera to record to SD card or tell me other keywords to find tutorials about this thanks

Comment: @Student-Art you may not find that.  Realistically, when you can buy a complete solution for maybe $12, and practical project solutions are built around highly integrated modules such as Stevenh linked, people just aren't going to be that interested in the project, as they would be in something which is not available in finished form, or which is built from a more open assortment of parts.

Comment: @ChrisStratton but i know that Kortuk  has a solution of this , i am waiting his answer

Comment: How is the 640x480 image going to fit to the 8 kB of MCU's memory? Or is it possible to push it directly to SD card from camera input?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just **make** by following a proven design, you could search the web for "CMUcam". You can actually cheat and buy a ready assembled CMUcam, but I'd leave the search as a little homework, and as a probe for your conscience. Of course, only a part of that project is of interest to you, i.e. mostly minus the "Bot".

If high frame-rate is not critical, and just a collection of images is fine, you might find [this](http://www.ladyada.net/make/IoTcamera/) Arduino based project interesting and instructional.

Also here [a $13.99, ready to use camera which does what you want, shipped to your home, for free](http://dx.com/p/300k-pixel-mini-camcorder-spy-camera-with-tf-card-slot-32022?rt=1&p=2&m=2&r=3&k=1&t=1&s=147256&u=32022). Gets you everything on the cheap, but of course, expect SMD electronics and you could order two, and perform a teardown, try to learn the electronics part, though you'd have no clue about the software.

If you really are in this for some honest-to-goodness learning experience, and not in a rush to shove a project out of door (/dorm room), search on the websites of Texas Instruments, Freescale etc., for something called "Application Notes", for "IP Camera", "Surveillance Camera" etc., and you'd fine some very educative material. However, you may not be able to easily make an end product, directly with it, but with some work. That is something this community can help with - lot more enthusiastically.

However, based on what your course is, and what are the actual expectations of your professors, you could take a completely different route, like use a USB-camera, an cheap SBC like the OlinuXino iMX.233 from Olimex, or a RaspberryPi, running linux, to do the whole thing. Hardly any different compared to using a USB webcam on a PC running linux.

Comment: A 14 dollar camera, inclusive shipping to Europe!, and then people complain that the charger doesn't work. Why aren't we surprised?

Comment: @icarus74 you have just 744 rep and your answer is usefull thanks a lot !

Comment: @icarus74 i will try to developp the CMUcam !

Comment: @Student-Art, if the answer is acceptable to you, you could indicate it by "Accepting" this as the answer, or if you believe it helped, but not completely the answer you were looking for, you could "Up vote".