# homemade camera with CMOS module SEN-08667 recording video

Tags: camera, cmos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [develop webcamera with battery and memory to SELF RECORDING (Disc Processing System)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42775/develop-webcamera-with-battery-and-memory-to-self-recording-disc-processing-sys)

im trying to build an own camera that have the following things and record video to the SD memory card

```
1- CMOS module camera (640x480)
2- battery compatible with the module
3-SD memory Card
4-button (start recording)
```

please what is the printed circuit board or shematics to connect all theres things and to record video from module to the SD card

PLEAAAAAAASE I AM NEW IN ELECTRONIC I DONT KNOW ABOUT THE MICRO CONTROLLER PLEASE HELP WITH MORE DEFINITIONS OR LINKS TO SOME EXEMPLES

thanks best regards

Comment: The hardest part of your system will be to capture pixel data from the camera. You need to provide more information about the output format of the camera.

Comment: Please provide internet addresses relating to components - especially camera IC and any application  notes you may know of.

Comment: If you don't bother to spell-check and capitalize, people are less likely to help you.

Comment: Please don't start a new question if want to elaborate on a previous one. You can edit the other question instead.

Comment: @stevenvh:- your wonderful answer got pirated...  ;)

Comment: @perilbrain - yes, I saw it :-). Russell is not to blame, he probably didn't know about the other question.

Comment: @stevenvh:- Not Russell, he did his job perfectly... but OP took your answer a step ahead, giving least credit to one excellently answered earlier.  :)

Comment: please guys help me to shunt the module camera with a micro controller to record video in this case to the SD card !

Answer (score 0):

[SEN-08667 Datasheet here](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Imaging/TCM8230MD.pdf) courtesy of Sparkfun. Camera IC $10 from them. 640 x 480 resolution.

[Sparkfun product page here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8667)

[image]

The diagram below is essentially the circuit diagram. I2C + data (from the data sheet). The signals are described in the data sheet. If that does not make enough sense to allow you to procedd then you probably would be far better off buying a more completely integrated camera.

[image]